# How to leave Bootstrap external content on the right?

Tags: html, css, statistics-bootstrap

Documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#external-content

Code:

```
 <div class="pos-f-t">
  <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
    <div class="bg-dark p-4">
      <h5 class="text-white h4">Collapsed content</h5>
      <span class="text-muted">Toggleable via the navbar brand.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </nav>
</div>
```

The default is for him to come up, but I want to leave him on the right. As?

Comment: what u actually want to display on right...?

Comment: You can use CSS to move the text and the button to the right.

Comment: I want to display external content, similar to this site: https://themes.2the.me/Boomerang/1.2/index.html